# How would paginate a json response in my GET request without the use of models/databases?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, pagination

I'd like to know how I can paginate multiples of 10 with the given [response](https://pastebin.com/X85Chzdn) in my GET request when it's not using databases/models.

I've searched around but I'm mostly seeing examples of database/model paginations and not json response paginations.

Below's what I've tried (along with so many other ways but I've ran out of options and hit a wall) but to no avail.

I know there's a way to do this simply but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.  Any feedback would be appreciated :).

```
$response = Http::get(env('endpoint'), $queryParams);

$results = $response->json()['results'];

$numResults = $response->json()['num_results']; 

$results->paginate(10); // multiples of ten.  I know this is the Model way of doing it but I can't find any other way to achieve this.
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/pagination#converting-results-to-json

Comment: @HashtagForgotName I'm not using a model at all.  It's a simple GET request I'm using only.  This is showing with the use of a model.

Comment: `Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Jsonable Interface contract and expose the toJson method, so it's very easy to convert your pagination results to JSON.` u can just turn any pagination result into a json response u don't need a model just your pagination result

Comment: so like this `DB::table('users')->paginate(15)` and then prob `->toJson()` behind it so something like this `DB::table('users')->paginate(15)->toJson()`

Comment: @HashtagForgotName I really appreciate your feedback but I'm not using a database.  This a json response from an endpoint.  I want to paginate the JSON response.  No database is being at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can collect the information:

```
collect($results)
```

Then paginate using ->skip(number_to_skip) and then ->take(number_to_take);

Then just return it like you're doing.
It'd be something like:

```
$page = $request->page;
$take = 10;
$skip = ($page - 1) * $take;
$resultsCount = collect($results)->count();
$results = collect($results)->skip($skip)->take($take)->all();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Jordan!  May you please provide a code sample of what you're referring to, please? :)

Comment: I added the code sample in the response.

Comment: got it, thanks.  I'm assuming `$page`'s the total number of results, right?

Comment: $take would be the number of results. $page would be which page the user is on.

To contextualize: if he is on page 1, we will skip 0 items and get 10. if he is on page 2, we will skip 10 items and get 10 more.

Comment: Don't we need to factor in the total number of results that's present in the GET response?

Comment: If you need to show the total results, you can just collect($results)->count(); You can check which functions you can use here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections

Comment: There is a gist here on paginating collections that might be useful: https://gist.github.com/vluzrmos/3ce756322702331fdf2bf414fea27bcb

Comment: Also see Laravel docs on manually creating a paginator. That might give you something a tad more useful than collection skip/take methods: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator

Comment: Can we somehow hop on a chat?  I have a few questions

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use de chunk method of collection

```
$results = collect($result);
$outputs = $results->chunck(20)[$request->input('page')];
```